# How to align multiple divs left and right in the same line in a responsive container (% width)?

Tags: html, css

I wanted the behaviour of inline-block and float together of several divs in a responsive container (% width), where:

1. float effect:

   1a. it would have divs left and right aligned

   1b. when the window width shrinks - the space between the left and right divs would also shrink
2. inline-block effect:

   2a. all the divs would be in the same line

   2b. when the window width shrinks - it will hide the divs (usually starting on the right)

Examples:

1. when the window is larger that the divs:
   [image: left and right divs same line - full window]
2. when the window is smaller that the divs:

   2a. the wanted effect
   [image: left and right divs same line - compressed- ok]

   2b. the wrong effect
   [image: left and right divs same line - compressed- wrong]

Here is a code example of what I got so far (which only simulates the float effect (1) and effect in same line (2b) but missing effect when shrinking the window width (3b) ), with a [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/seeker09/7p2t71fs/):

```css
.item1 {background-color: red;}
.item2 {background-color: yellow;}
.item3 {background-color: blue;}

#container {
  width: 95%;
  height: 50px; /* not sure if is needed */
}

#container div {
  display: inline-block; /* does nothing with floats */
  width:100px;
  height: 50px;
}

.left {float: left;}
.right {float: right;}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="item1 left">item1</div>
  <div class="item2 right">item2</div>
  <div class="item3 right">item3</div>
</div>
```

Notes:

1. The container has a % value (to be a bit responsive).
2. the width of the divs (items) is supposed to have a fixed width (to have a logo image, a menu, and some icons (more images), ...)
3. in the example, I've also added the inline-block just to show that it does not works with it
4. the example only uses 3 divs (1 left and 2 right), but if possible I preferred a solution where I could have more without changing too much of code.
   (I want to avoid fixed position (like right:20px or 20%) to be easier to add new items.)
5. was supposed to find a solution using only html and css (or html5 and css3) (avoiding JavaScript).

Comment: Why don't you use bootstrap for this?  http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: The disappearing of specific elements when below a certain width is probably easiest to achieve by using media queries to hide them altogether.

Comment: I'm a bit new to bootstrap, and css3, but I'll research any topic that is presented. About media queries, I preferred a more fluid solution without breaks (still thinking about float effect and inline-block affects together). I can understand English, but since it's not my native language, please excuse typing errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research and tests, I finally come up with a solution, with a **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/seeker09/uo67Ltpu/)**:

```css
.item1 {background-color: red;}
.item2 {background-color: yellow;}
.item3 {background-color: blue;}

#container {
    width: 95%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

/* affects container_left and container_right divs */
 #container > div {
    display: flex;
}
/* affects items */
 #container > div > div {
    width: 100px;
    min-width: 100px; /* to avoid shrinking in IE 11*/
    height: 50px;
}

#container, #container > div {
    /* reading from right to left (RTL)*/
    /* flex-direction: row-reverse; */
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="container_left">
        <div class="item1">item1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="container_right">
        <div class="item2">item2</div>
        <div class="item3">item3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notes:

- It does the effects asked, at least in Firefox (v 37.0.2) and Internet Explorer (IE 11).
- In chrome (v 42.0.2311.135 m) it doesn't respect the min-width. Maybe there's some way around it that I didn't realize.
- Changed the html to put 2 containers for left and right items, (and if needed you could also add a middle container). And in css using the flex property with the "justify-content: space-between" to align the containers.
- New items can be easily added to the right positions (just in html) without the need to use a grid system.
- Also added some css code to uncomment if you want to reverse the item order (in right to left languages).

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at bootstraps grid system.  It would save you a lot of time.  http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#gridSystem

Comment: Link to the most recent version: [http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Comment: Correct, either one will work perfectly.  What you are looking for is the Offsetting columns and the Fluid nesting section.  This is a really good tool to learn and use.

Comment: I'm not used to bootstrap, but for what I saw on the links above, you need to predefine the columns and breaking points of each column. I was just hoping for a more dynamic and simpler solution, but still it seems a good solution to considerate if no better alternative is found.

Comment: When you download the css from bootstrap it has all this set up.  All you have to do, is name your classes accordingly and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

May be it is not fully what you want, but it gets close:

use flex for the container, and hide the second row.

and play with flex-shrink, flex-basis, max-width and margin

```css
.container {
    width: 80%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: -100px;
    border: solid 1px red;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.container div {
    height: 100px;
    border: solid 1px;
}

.left {
    flex: 200px 0 0;
    background-color: lightgreen;
     margin-right: auto; 
}

.right {
    flex: 100px 1 1;
    background-color: yellow;
    max-width: 200px;
}

.disappears {
    flex: 200px 0 1;
    background-color: papayawhip;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="left">left</div>
<div class="right">right</div>
<div class="disappears">dis</div>
<div class="disappears">dis</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's a bit odd. The "right" item appears on the left and with no space from the "left" item, and even if it would appear right it would disapear (like the "dis" items") when i prefered the user to understand that there was more divs to the right. And betewen the left divs and the right divs it seems to be a predefined, and also if the window width is large enough, there appears 2 "right" divs items. However is good to know that there is a flex property that gives nice efects, it makes me want to dig a bit more on it :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `overflow:hidden;` to your `#container`

```
#container {
  width:    95%;
  height:   50px; /* not sure if is needed */
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: It makes the items disappear starting from the left (item3 and then item 2) instead of the reverse that was the intended, and if possible I would prefer to show the user that it could have more items (like half cut items (not sure how it is better)). At least if the order was right, it would be a simpler solution.